# shell_exec, popen, exec, passthru not working in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, exec, shell-exec

I have a requirement where i need to run a c program from codeigniter controller, the php shell commands are not wokring in the controller but, when the same commands are used from a simple php(without codeigniter) is working fine.

- I have checked the php.ini settings the shell_exec, exec, popen are enabled.

please help...

the command iam using is

```
$output = shell_exec("./hello"); //hello.c prints hello world.
echo $output;
```

the path printed using pwd was my home folder path where the C file is present.
the same command (shell_exec("./hello");) wont work in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

please check that you are giving the correct path to the exec command in the codeigniter.
Use below to check the current directory.

```
exec('pwd');
```

Also, if it is in the incorrect directory, do
provide the complete path.

Check if the c code file is in this directory or not. and change it accordingly if not.

Please provide the exec commands in your question too.

You should provide the absolute path in the exec command.

```
$output = shell_exec("/absolute/path/to/executable/hello"); //hello.c prints hello world.
echo $output;
```

Comment: hey nishant, the path provided for the c file is same in both the case, i have edited my question you could suggest something now.

Comment: hey, provide the complete path of the c file to execute it through CI.